# Validation fails in thymeleaf form but request still goes through

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm fairly new to thymeleaf (and spring mvc actually), but I've read the docs and I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a fairly standard form:

```
<form id="form" th:action="@{/next/page}" action="#" th:object="${form}" method="post">
```

and inside the form I have an input. I also use thymeleaf to validate the input on form submit. Validation looks something like:

```
th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('something')}" th:errors="*{something}">
```

My controller has a method with the following signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/next/page", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
  public String example(@Valid Form form, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{ 
    if(bindingRequest.hasErrors()) { 
       return page-my-form-is-on; 
    } 
   ... other stuff here ... 
}
```

When the form is submitted and there's a validation error, it seems like the page is still navigating to /next/page specified in the th:action, but when it loads, it is still the same page the form was on with the validation error message shown.

How can I cancel the request and prevent it from navigating to /next/page when there's a validation error? When there's a validation error I just want it to stay on the same page and display the error.

Comment: Does the data from the form get passed to the controller?

Comment: @Lukehey Yes it does

Comment: When you say it's 'navigating to /next/page' do you mean that the browser path shown is /next/page? If so then that is as expected as your form has submitted to to /next/page. You could redirect on error to a different path though that would be weird. The behaviour you describe is how I would expect form validation errors to work when posting a form and not using something ajaxy.